# Resources vs namespace in Rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

What is the difference between `resources` and `namespace`?

I have a `Rack` app inside a `gem` that I want to call from the `Rails` app.

```
namespace :app do
  get 'go', to: Gem::Controller.new
end
```

Since I have controller called AppController, can I use this one?

```
resources :app do
  collection do
    get 'go', to: Gem::Controller.new
  end
end
```

Which way is better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [Rails guide routing section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing)

Resources:

> Resource routing allows you to quickly declare all of the common
>   routes for a given resourceful controller. Instead of declaring
>   separate routes for your index, show, new, edit, create, update and
>   destroy actions, a resourceful route declares them in a single line of
>   code.

Namespace:

> You may wish to organize groups of controllers under a namespace. Most
>   commonly, you might group a number of administrative controllers under
>   an Admin:: namespace. You would place these controllers under the
>   app/controllers/admin directory, and you can group them together in
>   your router.

Eg:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :articles, :comments
end
```

---

But, I think what you meant was to choose between collection and namespacing.

It's like this, namespacing would be a better option if you are planning to have more routes for that app. Else, you can just use it as a collection.

Answer (score 1):

`resources` is a shortcut for generating seven routes needed for a [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) interface.

so `resources :app` would generate the following seven routes(patch and put routes are same):

```
get    "apps"          => "apps#index",   :as => 'apps'
get    "apps/:id"      => "apps#show",    :as => 'app'
get    "apps/new"      => "apps#new",     :as => 'new_app'
post   "apps"          => "apps#create",  :as => 'apps'
get    "apps/:id/edit" => "apps#edit",    :as => 'edit_app'
patch  "apps/:id"      => "apps#update",  :as => 'app'
put    "apps/:id"      => "apps#update",  :as => 'app'
delete "apps/:id"      => "apps#destroy", :as => 'app'
```

and then it would generate another route because of `get 'go', to: Gem::Controller.new`:

`/apps/go`

In case of namespace the `apps` seven REST routes won't be created but a named route for `apps/go` would be generated.